# Can't Integrate Google Places API

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-places-api

I am trying to use the GooglePlaces iOS API; however, every time I follow the directions for installing it via CocoaPods, I always get a Linker Command error. I've tried the steps about a million times and always get that error after building. Furthermore, I am using the workspace file that documentation recommends and I believe that I have followed all of the steps correctly. Can someone please help me?

Xcode version: 8.3.2 (8E2002)

Pod File Content:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'MoodSwings' do
pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

Xcode Error:

ld: framework not found GoogleMapsBase

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks!

Comment: whe need more details, show the error, the podfile content, those stuffs are important to try to help you

Comment: For sure! Sorry about that! The error is as follows: 

"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

..and the podfile looks like this:

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'MoodSwings' do
pod 'GooglePlaces'
end`

Comment: can you post what is inside of "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" this is the error title expand and please post in your question the error, also edit your question with the pod file content

Comment: Done! Check the updated question. I couldn't get any more detail on the error that what I posted. Essentially, it looks like the GoogleMaps framework couldn't be found

Comment: I think you need add pod GoogleMaps to your pod file and make pod install after that

Comment: Tried adding GoogleMaps to the pod file, but that still didn't work :(

Comment: What is your error now with GoogleMaps added?

Comment: Still seeing the following error: "ld: framework not found GoogleMaps"

Comment: clean your build, and try again is weird

Comment: Already tried cleaning my build several times and the same issue occurs

Comment: can you post your project in github or googleDrive to check it?

Comment: Here we go: https://github.com/PancakeSombrero/MoodsEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I Deintegrate Cocoapods from your project using this link [Deintegrating and Removing Cocoapods from your project](https://medium.com/@icanhazedit/remove-uninstall-deintegrate-cocoapods-from-your-xcode-ios-project-c4621cee5e42) after that using `pod init` I create pod file again this is the podfile updated content

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MoodSwings' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MoodSwings
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'

  target 'MoodSwingsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'MoodSwingsUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

After that I remove all configurations in `Build Setting` -> `Framework Search Path` and your project finally works!!

here is the repo [Github repo](https://github.com/rmelian2014/SOMoodsQuestion)

Comment: Oh wow! This make sense! Removing the Framework Search Path and relying on Cocoapods for installation is a scenario I should have tried. I'll add this as a commit to my current project! Thank you sooooo much; you are awesome!!!

Comment: @user958267 don't forgot accept my answer if solves your issue

Comment: After modifying my Podfile in the manner you noted and re-building my project, I get an error saying that the FBSDKCoreKit couldn't be found in LoginViewController.swift. Is this because the path to the SDK has now changed?

Comment: Ahh ok, so, I just cloned the project you posted and it built just fine (after I installed the pods), but I tried to do the same steps manually in my MoodsEngine repo, but kept getting the failure I noted; @Reinier Melian can you help me understand what you did?

Comment: Oh wow, so, now it totally works. I must have been missing some steps somehow. In any case, thank you so much for your help! I'll add the commit that fixes my issue to my MoodsEngine repo. Thanks again!!!